# IBOutlet UIViews are null?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, nib, iboutlet

I have a class called `ActorController` and it has a NIB file. I have created `IBOutlet`s in `ActorController.h` that match up with various `UIView`s and `UIImageView`s in the NIB file. However, these views never show up on the screen like they should. Upon further investigation, I have discovered that if i use `NSLog` to print the UIView object to the console, it prints `null`. Could anybody suggest what I may be doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be you forgot to bind all IBOutlets ?

Comment: Are they properly bound? To check if they are, see the circle to the left of the outlets @property lines in ActorController.h. If there's any empty circle, go to Interface Builder to correct them.

Comment: Are you printing them in your init method? Because the IB object doesn't get initialized until awakeFromNib

Comment: IBOutlets are bound properly, and I am printing them in a method called `setup` which gets called after `awakeFromNib` (I think.) This is worth double checking though. EDIT: Indeed, it is called after `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to look for:

- Nib not loading at all:

  - wrong name
  - nib file not included in project
  - capitalization problems (iOS is case-sensitive on the device)
- outlets not connected (views should still show up on screen, though)
- outlets connected, but to wrong object
- view controller created and initialized properly, but not displayed
- active view controller is not the one you initialized from the nib

Comment: The NIB is definitely loading and outlets are connected. The root view controller is ViewController, does ActorController have to have some direct relation to it?

Comment: The instance of ActorController that you create has to somehow become the active view controller. Maybe you push it onto the navigation stack (if you're using a nav controller), or you make it the window's root view controller, etc. Just *having* an instance of ActorController doesn't mean that it'll be displayed, though -- you have to make that happen.